# How to redirect to saml logout from spring controller class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

in our spring boot application I want to redirect to saml/logout when unauthorised(401) exception comes in controller class.for redirecting I am doing this from jsp

```
response.sendRedirect("/saml/logout");
```

I saw this mapping in log

```
DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/saml/logout/**'], [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter@6e836dbc]
```

Please suggest how can I do it?